# change input into int while its being placed into dictionary

Tags: python, csv, converters

Is there any way to while reading into this dictionary to convert the values of each key value to int? Originally they are strings but i would prefer them to be ints. This is what i tried but i am getting errors! Each key looks like {'USA': ('123,123', '312,321,321')} But i want those numbers to be ints

```
**def _demo_fileopenbox():        
msg  = "Pick A File!"
msg2 = "Select a country to learn more about!"
title = "Open files"
default="*.py"
f = fileopenbox(msg,title,default=default)
writeln("You chose to open file: %s" % f)

countries = {}

with open(f,'r') as handle:
    reader = csv.reader(handle, delimiter = '\t')  
    for row in reader:
        countries[row[0]] = ((int(row[1])),(int(row[2])))
    while 1:
        reply = choicebox(msg=msg2, choices= list(countries.keys()) )
        writeln(reply + ";\tArea: " + (countries[reply])[0] + "\tPopulation: " + (countries[reply])[1] )
  **
```

thanks!

Comment: have you tried removing the commas before converting?

Comment: is there a way to do this as its being read in?

Comment: Yes there is, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the commas from the strings before converting them to `int`s:

```
countries[row[0]] = (int(row[1].replace(',', '')), int(row[2].replace(',', '')))
```

Comment: thanks for the help but when i do that i get this error? any ides? ** countries[row[0]] = (int(row[1].replace(',', '')), int(row[2].replace(',', '')))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''**

Comment: That means that there are other non number characters in those cells. Insert a `print row` before that line to see what you're getting.

Comment: oh i think there are spaces at the end of the numbers. any way to get rid of those too. Its just the way that the text was originally delimitered

Comment: Whitespaces shouldn't break `int()`. What's the last line that prints before the error?

Comment: if i take off the int part this is a sample of the output if i just print(countries) : {'France ': ('211208', '64057792'), 'Kazakhstan ': ('1049150', '15399437'), 'Vanuatu ': ('4710', '218519')..... so the removing the commas is working but it wont convert to int

Comment: Again, what is the last line that prints *before* the error? You should be inserting this `print` before attempting to convert to `int()`, but you should still be trying to convert to `int()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your numbers contain commas. Change the code to this:

```
for row in reader:
    countries[row[0]] = tuple(int(a.replace(",","")) for a in row[1:])
```